# C# MongoDB Driver run mongo query directly

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there a way to run a mongodb query directly using the c# driver? I have the following query in mongodb:

```
db.EventEntries.distinct("Computer")
```

that returns the correct results what appears to be instantaneously. When running the command the way I saw how to run in using the c# driver,

```
var result = collection.AsQueryable().Select(r => r.Computer).Distinct().ToList();
```

it returns the results in 41194 milliseconds. When I use mongodb profiler I see the command that it is translated to is actually using aggregate and a pipeline. Is there a way to run the distinct query in the same way as the native dictinct query? Or is there a better way to run it in the C# driver? I'm using version 2.4.3 of the MongoDB driver.

EDIT: I've ran the query several times in a row in C# and it is anywhere from the original 41194 milliseconds to 69301 milliseconds. The query it creates is

`db.EventEntries.aggregate([{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$Computer" } }])}`

which if I run directly in Mongo shell it takes 59147 milliseconds to complete according to the profiler.

Comment: Before you jump. Try running the operation a couple of times. You are likely just seeing the "uncached" response time on an intial query, which is different to the `.distinct()` you are running. If consistently longer, then that is surprising, What actually is the aggregation statement being generated? Can you include that content from the profiler into your question?

Comment: Interesting. There "should" just be a [`.Distinct()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Distinct.htm) method on the collection. ( at least the docs agree ). It's basically the same syntax as the shell method. `collection.Distinct("Computer")`. Surprising that you see such a time difference though.

Comment: It took me some digging to figure out how to get the `.Distinct()` method on the collection itself to work. If you change that from a comment to an answer I can mark it as the correct answer. I used it and it worked. Took 77 miliseconds. `FieldDefinition<EventLogEntry, string> field = "Computer";` `var result = collection.Distinct(field, FilterDefinition<EventLogEntry>.Empty).ToList();`